# Customizing NewForm in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, newform

I am currently using SharePoint to set up a vacation request system. I have created the following lists

**Vacation Request**

**Vacation Request Dates**

**Vacation Request history**

On the NewForm for Vacation request, I have created a button that pop's up the NewForm for Vacation Request Dates to be able to add dates. I am trying to figure out once the user hits save to show those dates on the NewForm for Vacation Request the user is currently filling out.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem? Also, how would I tie those dates to that record?  My thought for setting up a Dates list was so they could choose a different category for separate days in the request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider creating simple UI that pops up from the "Vacation Request" form, and that popup contains custom CSOM code that adds item to Dates list.

After that you don't even need to query Dates list for the latest item as you should already know what dates the user defined, and can show those on the NewForm of "Vacation Requests".

Or if you want to use OOB NewForm of the Dates list, you could query for the latest item created by current user after popup closes via REST call to URL such as

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('LIST_TITLE')/items?$top=1&$select=VacationStartDate,VacationEndDate&$orderby=Created%20desc&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/ID eq USERID
```

USERID for current user is quickest to get from `_spPageContextInfo.userId` already available on page.

Answer (score 0):

In Vacation Request list, we can create two date columns("Vacation Date From", "Vacation Date To"), and using those two columns to store the vacation date.

If you want to split the Vacation Request Dates in a list, we can create a lookup column(allow multiple) in the Vacation Request list.